iOS and Focus on Search Form on a Webpage: Unwanted Enlargement of the whole page
I have a form field of the type "search" on a valid* page:
<search>
    <form action=https://cse.google.com/cse method=get target=_blank>
      <input type=hidden name=cx value=740064496d7e741b9>
      <input type=search name=q title="Suchen in allen Ausgaben von Pro Velo – via Google" placeholder="Suchen in allen Ausgaben von Pro Velo – via Google">
    </form>
</search>

The code ist part of my page: https://provelo.fahrradzukunft.de/
In 3 Browsers on macOS everything is fine with the behaviour of the search field.
But on Safari on iOS 18.2 touching the search field (setting the focus on the field) causes the entire content of the page to be enlarged:


What is the cause of the enlargement and how can I prevent it?
*checked on https://validator.w3.org/
The error message "search is not allowed inside header" is an error of the validator. Of course it is allowed.
